# Can someone identify the pattern of these purses?

Tags: crocheting, yarn, pattern-drafting

I would like to identify the pattern of the purse in the image below, and want to know how to begin the chain number of the stitch. Is it a double crochet or single crochet? What type of yarn do I use for this?

[image]

Comment: It looks like primarily single crochet. The flower looks like double crochet. If you are a member of knit & crochet community called ravellry you will find many groups you can post your question in. You will also be able to search the patterns posted. I will send your question to a friend who made a similar purse about 6years ago. Maybe she will respond.

Comment: Hi Valentine, I have edited your post and left in (and rephrased what I think were) the questions you were asking, but please focus on a single question. You can always ask other questions using the [New Question] button on the main page. Also, can you tell us where you found this picture? It is important to cite your sources. Welcome to Arts & Crafts!

Answer (score 0):

I'm about 99% sure that isn't crochet, Tunisian or otherwise, but knitting. There are quite a few "diagonal" knitting stitch patterns out there, and this looks to be one of them, made with knit and slipped stitches. Look up "diagonal basketweave knitting pattern," which seems close. It's finished with crochet slip stitches all along the opening, and of course, the flower. A pattern for a similar flower would be:

Ch 6, sl st. in first ch to form ring.
*ch 4, tr 3. ch 4, sl st in to loop* rep. italicized portion 5 more times for a total of 6 "petals"

This flower is very similar, although in the picture it does look as if maybe that one was done by making single crochets in a magic ring and THEN making the petals by going in to the sc stitches. And also they seem to only have 5 petals, and something I can't make out to attach it to the purse. Maybe 10 sc in a loose magic ring or a ring of chains, going in to every other one on the second round.

Comment: Hi Sarah, the weave you suggest indeed seems a closer fit than the crochet mentioned in the other answer. I think a picture would have really helped, instead of saying "look it up", as that requires verification from others. And another heads-up: your answer is mostly about the flower in the OP's picture, which is incidental. If you think such info is good to share, you can always ask a new question and provide your own answer. Here it seems a little out of place. IIC: welcome to Arts & Crafts!

Answer (score -2):

This looks like tunisian crochet.

[image]

Here's an article about how to get started with it https://www.purlsoho.com/create/tunisian-crochet-basics/.  Cotton seems to be the most common type of yarn for handbags.  I'd recommend a cotton cord yarn for extra durability and to show off the stitch texture.

Comment: Looks similar but the handbags have a diagonal offset which your link lacks. Also just providing a link for an answer is not so useful for SE because links go bad...